# Symfony использование параметров

Tags: php, symfony

Пишу парсер html сайтов и так как нет уникального алгоритма поиска данных, задаю в виде массива параметры, которые сообщают, где искать контент. Так я указываю где искать ссылки, заголовки, описание, контент, какие элементы нужно удалить и т.д. Сейчас я храню эти параметры в виде ассоциативного массива и при создании класса, сохраняю их как свойство класса в конструкторе, например.

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->dom = [
        'lifehacker.ru' => [
            'posts_links' => 'div[class=content]',
            'title_dom' => 'body h1',
            'image_dom' => '.entry-content a img',
            'excerpt_dom' => '.the-excerpt p',
            'content_dom' => '.entry-content',
            'remove_elements' =>  [
                'script',
                'div[class=entry-details]',
                'p[class=wp-caption-text],
                div[class=lh-post-source-view]',
                'div[class=jp-relatedposts]',
                'div[class=social-likes]',
                'div[class=the-excerpt]',
                'p[class=wp-thumbnail-caption']
        ]
}
```

Если сайтов будет даже хотя бы 5, выйдет огромный конструктор, что не есть хорошо(
Еще я пробовал хранить это в базе данных и вызывать из полей, но этот способ работает медленее, и по-моему это тоже не хорошее решение.

Подскажите, где лучше задавать и хранить эти параметры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно хранить в config-файлах.

Например, в `app/config/sites/lifehacker.ru.php` или `app/config/sites/lifehacker.ru.yml`. Так будет проще отслеживать изменения в системе контроля версий.

Но, вообще, и в базе данных должно быть нормально, особенно, если использовать кеширование - http://blog.alterphp.com/2014/05/doctrine2-optimization-with-apc-cache.html

Скачивание и парсинг страниц всё равно будут занимать больше 90% времени.

Comment: Если использовать кеш доктрины, происходит переполнение памяти, не знаю почему. Вариант с конфигом подошел бы. Только как потом эти данные вытянуть в контроллер?

Comment: `$this->get('app.my_config_loader')->getConfig('lifehacker.ru');`, а в этом сервисе `Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($path . '/' . $siteName . '.yml'))`, а путь к `$path` передавать через DI - `"%kernel.root_dir%/config"`

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)